# openVPN Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET

Tags: vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, ubuntu-18.04, vpn-client

I am having issues connecting to my VPN, with port forwarding set correctly as I can VPN into my other lubuntu machine, also UFW is disabled. Can someone please guide my as to what I am missing in my config?? Also additionally when i turn on my UFW i can ping WAN or websites by names like google.com, but cannot ping workgroup computers by name but only when i add ".local" suffix with computer names i can ping in LAN.

I hope the above question is not connected to my openVPN configuration. As this is networking issue i felt to add the UFW issue too. Below is my detailed config :

Hi there here is my openvpn.log file :

```
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jan  9 2019
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=enp1s0 HWADDR=e0:d5:5e:ed:f5:63
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Listening for incoming TCP connection on [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 GID set to root
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 UID set to owner
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=1024 maxevents=1028
Thu Jun 13 16:54:01 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

my server.conf file :

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user owner
group root
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Heres my ifconfig :

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.201  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::29bb:768f:77ea:c4fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:d5:5e:ed:f5:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14381  bytes 8571949 (8.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11387  bytes 1826373 (1.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2333  bytes 233564 (233.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2333  bytes 233564 (233.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Heres my client log :

```
2019-06-13 16:42:06 Building configuration…
2019-06-13 16:42:06 started Socket Thread
2019-06-13 16:42:06 WARNING:  Compression enabled, Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Enabling decompression of received packet only. Sent packets are not compressed.
2019-06-13 16:42:06 Current Parameter Settings:
2019-06-13 16:42:06   config = '/data/user/0/de.blinkt.openvpn/cache/android.conf'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mode = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   show_ciphers = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   show_digests = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   show_engines = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   genkey = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   connect_retry_max = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06 Connection profiles [0]:
2019-06-13 16:42:06   proto = tcp-client
2019-06-13 16:42:06   local = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   local_port = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote = 'sg10.ddns.net'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_port = '1194'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_float = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   bind_defined = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   bind_local = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   bind_ipv6_only = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   connect_retry_seconds = 2
2019-06-13 16:42:06   connect_timeout = 120
2019-06-13 16:42:06   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   socks_proxy_port = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tun_mtu = 1500
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   link_mtu = 1500
2019-06-13 16:42:06   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tun_mtu_extra = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mtu_discover_type = -1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   fragment = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mssfix = 1450
2019-06-13 16:42:06   explicit_exit_notification = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_auth_file = '[[INLINE]]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   key_direction = 1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_crypt_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_crypt_v2_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06 Connection profiles END
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_random = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   dev = 'tun'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   topology = 1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_local = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_nowarn = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   shaper = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mtu_test = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mlock = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   keepalive_ping = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   keepalive_timeout = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   inactivity_timeout = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ping_send_timeout = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ping_rec_timeout = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remap_sigusr1 = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   persist_tun = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   persist_key = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   passtos = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
2019-06-13 16:42:06   resolve_in_advance = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   username = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   groupname = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   down_pre = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   up_restart = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   up_delay = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   daemon = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   inetd = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   log = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   machine_readable_output = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   nice = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   verbosity = 4
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mute = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   gremlin = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   status_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   status_file_version = 1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   status_file_update_freq = 60
2019-06-13 16:42:06   occ = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   rcvbuf = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   sndbuf = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   sockflags = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   fast_io = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   comp.alg = 2
2019-06-13 16:42:06   comp.flags = 1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_default_metric = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_noexec = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_delay = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_delay_window = 30
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_nopull = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_addr = '/data/user/0/de.blinkt.openvpn/cache/mgmtsocket'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_port = 'unix'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_log_history_cache = 250
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   management_flags = 16678
2019-06-13 16:42:06   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   key_direction = 1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ciphername = 'AES-128-CBC'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ncp_enabled = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ncp_ciphers = 'AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   authname = 'SHA256'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
2019-06-13 16:42:06   keysize = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   engine = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   replay = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   replay_window = 64
2019-06-13 16:42:06   replay_time = 15
2019-06-13 16:42:06   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   test_crypto = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_server = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_client = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   key_method = 2
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ca_file = '[[INLINE]]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   dh_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   cert_file = '[[INLINE]]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   extra_certs_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   priv_key_file = '[[INLINE]]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   cipher_list_tls13 = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_cert_profile = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   verify_x509_type = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ns_cert_type = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 65535
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   remote_cert_eku = 'TLS Web Server Authentication'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   ssl_flags = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_timeout = 2
2019-06-13 16:42:06   renegotiate_bytes = -1
2019-06-13 16:42:06   renegotiate_packets = 0
2019-06-13 16:42:06   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
2019-06-13 16:42:06   handshake_window = 60
2019-06-13 16:42:06   transition_window = 3600
2019-06-13 16:42:06   single_session = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   push_peer_info = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_exit = DISABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_crypt_v2_genkey_type = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_crypt_v2_genkey_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   tls_crypt_v2_metadata = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06   client = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   pull = ENABLED
2019-06-13 16:42:06   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
2019-06-13 16:42:06 OpenVPN 2.5-icsopenvpn [git:icsopenvpn/v0.7.8-0-g168367a5] arm64-v8a [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 22 2019
2019-06-13 16:42:06 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018, LZO 2.10
2019-06-13 16:42:06 MANAGEMENT: Connected to management server at /data/user/0/de.blinkt.openvpn/cache/mgmtsocket
2019-06-13 16:42:06 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'version 3'
2019-06-13 16:42:06 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2019-06-13 16:42:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 2'
2019-06-13 16:42:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'proxy NONE'
2019-06-13 16:42:07 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2019-06-13 16:42:07 Network Status: CONNECTED LTE to MOBILE www
2019-06-13 16:42:07 Debug state info: CONNECTED LTE to MOBILE www, pause: userPause, shouldbeconnected: true, network: SHOULDBECONNECTED
2019-06-13 16:42:07 Debug state info: CONNECTED LTE to MOBILE www, pause: userPause, shouldbeconnected: true, network: SHOULDBECONNECTED
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2019-06-13 16:42:08 LZO compression initializing
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1624 D:1170 EF:80 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1624 D:1450 EF:124 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1572,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1572,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
2019-06-13 16:42:08 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET6]64:ff9b::b639:694a:1194
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Socket Buffers: R=[4194304->4194304] S=[524288->524288]
2019-06-13 16:42:08 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET6]64:ff9b::b639:694a:1194 [nonblock]
2019-06-13 16:42:08 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1560424328,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
2019-06-13 16:42:08 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'needok 'PROTECTFD' ok'
2019-06-13 16:42:09 TCP connection established with [AF_INET6]64:ff9b::b639:694a:1194
2019-06-13 16:42:09 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'needok 'PROTECTFD' ok'
2019-06-13 16:42:09 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2019-06-13 16:42:09 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET6]64:ff9b::b639:694a:1194
2019-06-13 16:42:09 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1560424329,WAIT,,,,,,
2019-06-13 16:42:09 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2019-06-13 16:42:09 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
2019-06-13 16:42:09 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2019-06-13 16:42:09 Waiting 2s seconds between connection attempt
2019-06-13 16:42:09 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1560424329,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,,,,
2019-06-13 16:42:14 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2019-06-13 16:42:14 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'proxy NONE'
2019-06-13 16:42:14 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 2'
2019-06-13 16:42:14 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2019-06-13 16:42:15 LZO compression initializing
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1624 D:1170 EF:80 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1624 D:1450 EF:124 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1572,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1572,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
2019-06-13 16:42:15 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]182.57.105.74:1194
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Socket Buffers: R=[4194304->4194304] S=[524288->524288]
2019-06-13 16:42:15 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]182.57.105.74:1194 [nonblock]
2019-06-13 16:42:15 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1560424335,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
2019-06-13 16:42:15 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'needok 'PROTECTFD' ok'
2019-06-13 16:42:16 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]182.57.105.74:1194
2019-06-13 16:42:16 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'needok 'PROTECTFD' ok'
2019-06-13 16:42:16 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2019-06-13 16:42:16 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]182.57.105.74:1194
2019-06-13 16:42:16 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1560424336,WAIT,,,,,,
2019-06-13 16:42:16 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2019-06-13 16:42:16 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
2019-06-13 16:42:16 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2019-06-13 16:42:16 Waiting 2s seconds between connection attempt
```

Answer (score 16):

This message is printed when **no IPv4/v6 preference is given in the config** (i.e. proto udp/tcp is used) and OpenVPN is running as a server. 
Just change in server.conf on what you need udp4/upd6:

```
;proto udp
proto udp4
```

**Updated:** For tcp protocol (not udp) just change in server.conf on what you need tcp4/tcp6:

```
;proto tcp
proto tcp4
```

Comment: This is a TCP configuration and the IPv6 to IPv4 failover seems to be working in the client logfiles. This does not seem to be the answer the question poster is looking for.

Comment: Thank you Joffrey, I updated my answer. See above. OpenVPN didn't work for me with the same question poster, and I'm sharing a solution that help me.

Comment: Also, note that it is not an error, just an information on which address family was chosen. See also here: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/805

Answer (score 0):

Some of your problem could be the fact of somebody trying to D dos your server at least
that what happen to my server everything was going well and when I set up OpenVpn it worked
flawless no issue when I got hit and happen to reinstall the Os and reinstall Openvpn the error had occurred.  This may or may not be your problem and I do hope this method will help.

First off - Troubleshoot the problem.

The ifconfig means that you do not have the required package install
so when you go and type in ifconfig it will not display interface configuration
to fix that you will need to install net-tools

yum install net-tools

Now the could not determine IPv4/IPv6  You may not have to disable IPv6 you can
if you wish to do so but I Don't believe it will fix your problem however if it does
Congrats.

The next thing you should do is edit your iptables to allow openvpn your firewall could
be blocking the configuration required to run openvpn.

You can use this to help you configure iptables to allow your openvpn to run https://arashmilani.com/post?id=53

Also you may want to install fail2ban https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7  You may not think this have anything to do to solve the issue however it is best to keep scrub from trying to break in to your VPS.  If you prefer to use something else go ahead and use that.

Next you may need to enabled httpd  https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-on-centos-7/   this may also help fix your issue.

Next thing you may want to do is use iptables to help fight against D dos attacked.
https://javapipe.com/blog/iptables-ddos-protection/ < that should help you or you can 
use another source to help you set up your vps to help fight against ddos or install 
your own firewall.  Here are some firewall you could install please note you may want to disable the built in firewall  if your vps already have a firewall built in.

iptables
firewalld
csf
IPCop FireWall
Shorewall - Iptables made easy
pfSense
Untangle NG Firewall
UFW - Uncomplicated Firewall
IPFire
Smoothwall Express
VyOS
Vuurmuur

Reason to use iptables or some kind of firewall to help fight against D dos is because if a lot of traffic is being sent to your network it may prevent you from using openvpn.

- If you do not trust the link I provided you can research other link to help set up your vps to fight against D dos attack that may be being sent to your vps.

I do hope this help and you may want to install and make sure you have other package
that you may need install if you do not have them.

You can also check and see if you have the latest open ssl installed the latest version
is v1.0.2  if you are running on v1.0.1 you should be good to go or you may want to consider upgrading your open ssl.

Comment: Don't bother with ifconfig. It's obsolete anyway, that's why it is not installed by default. You should be using `ip` commands instead.