# Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol

Tags: openvpn, protocol

I am having this problem all of a sudden.  Open VPN worked brilliantly until December 2021- then it stopped connecting with the following reason:

RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: xxxx.xxxx.com:xxxx (No such host is known. )
Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol.

I have hidden the host address and port designations- but hopefully you get the idea.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as this service is no longer reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This message is printed when no IPv4/v6 preference is given in the config (i.e. proto udp/tcp is used) and OpenVPN is running as a server. Just change in server.conf on what you need udp4/upd6:

```
;proto udp
proto udp4
```

***Updated***: For tcp protocol (not udp) just change in server.conf on what you need tcp4/tcp6:

```
;proto tcp
proto tcp4
```

[Original Source](https://serverfault.com/a/982184)